# Bash command substution error

Tags: bash, cron, init.d

**The code:**

```
`cat <(fgrep -i -v "$DAEMON_TEST" <(sudo -u asm crontab -l)) <(echo "$CRON") | sudo -u asm crontab -`
```

**The error:**

```
command substitution: line 46: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/etc/init.d/asm: command substitution: line 46: `cat <(fgrep -i -v "$DAEMON_TEST" <(sudo -u asm crontab -l)) <(echo "$CRON") | sudo -u asm crontab -'
```

The command runs fine when run directly into the shell by replacing the variables with the relevant strings

Here are **the variables:**

```
DAEMON_TEST=asm_test.php
CRON="*/15 * * * * /opt/asm/daemons/test.php"
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what this command does but im 100% sure it shouldn't need this many command & process substitutions and pipes

Comment: You have DAEMON_CONTROLLER as a variable and you are using DAEMON_TEST in the command sub?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can replace `<(echo "$CRON")` with `<<< "$CRON`

Comment: It checks to see if DAEMON_TEST is found as a cron job, if it is, that line is replaced with CRON. If not, it is appended.

Comment: @Jaypal: I pasted in the incorrect variable, there is a variable called DAEMON_TEST.php

Comment: Thats wrong. why do you enclose the command with `\``

Comment: If I don't, I get the following syntax error `syntax error near unexpected token \`('`

Comment: What different do you do when running it on command line and inside your script?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa Also remove the back ticks or do you run as is?

Comment: Check my answer. The issue was with the hash bang.

Comment: `cat <fgrep -i -v "$DAEMON_TEST"`, as suggested by the edit, is absolutely wrong -- it's identical to `cat -i -v "$DAEMON_TEST" <fgrep`, which is reading from a file named `fgrep` as input. Answers should be added as answers, not edits to the question -- that way they're subject to votes &c. on their correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being completely unrelated.

Changed:

```
#/bin/sh
```

to:

```
#/bin/bash
```

I never realized there would be a differnce

https://superuser.com/questions/125728/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-and-sh

Comment: Specifically, process substitution `<()` is not supported by `sh`.